# Android textview incorrect linebreaking

Tags: android, textview

Below is some text from a textview (background is red for emphasis on the boundaries).

As you can see, the word "the" before "digital generation" should have been in the previous line since there was enough space. Is there any way to make TextView render it correctly?

I tried `android:breakStrategy="high_quality"` without luck.

[image]

Comment: Add yout layout (`TextView` in enough) ans text which you are trying fit there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like adding `android:breakStrategy="simple"` solves it